# Export users and their profiles from Drupal 6 database

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

As the title says: I'm a newbie drupal user and I need to automatize the export of the "username" from the table user and some related fields from the "content_type_profile" table. 
I guess I shouldn't use any kind of module to try to get out this data since I need to run a script and generate a separated data from the html page and generate a pdf as it is needed. So I tried to join togheter both of the tables by using:

```
select name, field_username_value, field_surname_value from users as u inner join content_type_profile as p on u.uid = p.vid;
```

But I found out that the uid and the vid in the content table doesn't match and I can't find where is the third table I need to get this relation working. I can't find any documentation which simply explaines how Drupal manage these content_type tables either. 
- How can achieve this kind of export from the Drupal db? 
- Can anyone please point me out to which documents do I need to read to achieve my goal?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `node` table you need to join in:

```
SELECT u.name, ctp.field_username_value, ctp.field_surname_value
FROM users u
INNER JOIN node n ON n.uid = u.uid
INNER JOIN content_type_profile ctp ON ctp.vid = n.vid
```

The content type tables are provided by the [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck), they're not part of Drupal core; that might be why you're struggling to find documentation (though there is plenty out there).

Comment: Yeah! You got it! Thanks Clive, your query is working like a charm and the link point out exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again